# PHP - wrong switch / case statement

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

i am using simple PHP script which display crashes on the care based on data from XML. So what it do is : Put image with no crashes to site (its in div class outer), and after i just check XML and if value = "Y" it should display image over it. Problem is i never get display "front" image, instead of that i always just get "," instead of `<div class = "front">`

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
$first_damage_zone = true;
//loop through the damage zones as key value pairs
echo '<div class="outer">' ; //show blanked car image
foreach ( $claim ['damage'] ['general'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ($value == 'Y') {
        if ($first_damage_zone) {
        }
        switch ($key) {
            case 'roof' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_ROOF;
                echo '<div class="roof"></div>';
                break;
            case 'underbody' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_UNDERBODY;
                break;  
            case 'front' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_FRONT;
                echo '<div class="front"></div>';
                break;
            case 'front-left' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_FRONTLEFT;
                echo '<div class="front-left"></div>';
                break;
            case 'front-right' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_FRONTRIGHT;
                echo '<div class="front-right"></div>';
                break;
            case 'rear' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_REAR;
                echo '<div class="rear"></div>';
                break;
            case 'rear-left' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_REARLEFT;
                echo '<div class="rear-left"></div>';
                break;
            case 'rear-right' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_REARRIGHT;
                echo '<div class="rear-right"></div>';
                break;
            case 'mechanical' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_MECHANICAL;
                break;
            case 'interior' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_INTERIOR;
                break;
            case 'center' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_CENTER;
                echo '<div class="roof"></div>';
                break;
            case 'side-left' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_SIDELEFT;
                echo '<div class="car-left"></div>';
                break;
            case 'side-right' :
                @$key = $_VIN_QUERY_DAMAGED_ZONES_SIDERIGHT;
                echo '<div class="car-right"></div>';
                break;
        echo '<div>';
        }
        if ($first_damage_zone) {
            print $key;
            $first_damage_zone = false;
        } else {
            print ', ' . $key;
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. I am sure that in XML there is tag front and i am sure there is value Y in it as well. So this confuse me :(

XML:

```
-
<damage>-
    <general>
        <front>Y</front>
        <front-left>Y</front-left>
        <front-right>N</front-right>
        <interior>N</interior>
        <mechanical>N</mechanical>
        <rear>N</rear>
        <rear-left>N</rear-left>
        <rear-right>N</rear-right>
        <roof>N</roof>
        <side-left>Y</side-left>
        <side-right>N</side-right>
        <underbody>N</underbody>
    </general>
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($key, $value)` to see what's really coming out of your array?

Comment: Can you post your XML? Or rather, can you post `$claim ['damage'] ['general']`, as it's very difficult to debug without it.

Comment: Why the @$key ? Do you use simplexml?

Comment: XML:
`-<damage>


-<general>

<front>Y</front>

<front-left>Y</front-left>

<front-right>N</front-right>

<interior>N</interior>

<mechanical>N</mechanical>

<rear>N</rear>

<rear-left>N</rear-left>

<rear-right>N</rear-right>

<roof>N</roof>

<side-left>Y</side-left>

<side-right>N</side-right>

<underbody>N</underbody>

</general>`

Comment: and var_dump ($key) gives result: string(9) "side-left" and string(10) "front-left"
So no FRONT there :(

Comment: How do you set $claim ?

Comment: XML is pretty big, i am using that $claim like 50 times before with no problem. Part of my code which work is here:
`$claim ['vehicle']['engine-kw']`

This is how i set claim
`foreach ( $array ['result'] ['claim'] as $claim )`